# DlangUI: Можно ли вывести ListWidget по 5 элементов в строке

Tags: d

Здравствуйте, может кто-то знает как вывести через ListWidget по 5 элементов в строке. Или ограничит кол-во элементов в строке в зависимости от ширины главного окна приложения, чтобы если элементы не умещаются в одной строке, выводить их на следующей и так далее пока элементы не закончатся.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В ListWidget такой функциональности сейчас нет.
Можно попробовать TableLayout.